# How can I able to show that $(S ^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $S\subseteq H$ be a finite subset.  How can I able to show that $(S ^{\perp})^{\perp}$
is a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: You could try to prove that $S^\perp=\mbox{Span} S^\perp$. And that $(M^\perp)^\perp=\overline{M}$ for every subspace $M$. These are two well-known and useful facts of Hilbert spaces. Now if $S$ is finite, its span is finite-dimensional, and equal to its closure.

Comment: not get it.please explain more.

Comment: [See here, p.10](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=conway+functional+analysis&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=j3p9Ucr0IorR0wHGtIDYCA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to prove is that, for any $S\subset H$, 
$$
S^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\mbox{span}\,S}
$$
One inclusion is easy if you notice that $S^{\perp\perp}$ is a closed subspace that contains $S$. The other inclusion follows from 
$$
H=\overline{\mbox{span}\,S}\oplus S^\perp
$$
and the uniqueness of the orthogonal complement.

Comment: In this case $S$ is finite so $\rm{span} S$ is a finite dimensional subspace which is actually closed so we have $S^{\perp \perp}=\rm{span} S$... I wanted to say  this because, I was guessing we need to have $S^{\perp \perp}=\rm{span} S$.. I was very close but not quite correct.. This was helpful.. Thanks